# Function running after data loading still gives an error because data is not loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting Binance coin data from Binance npm package. But when I try to run filter or map function it gives the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

The code:

```
const client = Binance();

  const [dataLoading, setDataLoaded] = useState(true);
  const [tradesData, setTradesData] = useState();
  const [length, setLength] = useState();

  const tradesDataSet = async () => {
    setTradesData(await client.trades({ symbol: "BTCUSDT" }));

    setDataLoaded(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    tradesDataSet();
  }, []);
  console.log(
    tradesData.filter((trade) => trade.price * trade.qty > 3000).length
  );
```

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: `useEffect` happens asynchronously. That means your react component has to handle before `tradesData` has been set. One way to do this would be to give it an initial value, perhaps an empty array, like `const [tradesData, setTradesData] = useState([]);`

Comment: ^ Or add a guard clause to handle unloaded data `if (dataLoading) return <>loading...</>;` and place the code using `tradesData` behind the guard clause.